# Wait for function to complete its ajax before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    doSomething();
    var a = getSomething();
})

function doSomething(){
    $.ajax(
        //insert something to database here
    )
}
```

How do I make sure `doSomething()` has already finished its ajax call before calling `getSomething()` without using `async: false` or changing the code inside `doSomething()` method?

Comment: write getSomething() method inside complete callback of doSomething() ajax call without this you can't control ajax async calls

Comment: @FrebinFrancis That would require changing the code inside `doSomething`...

Comment: Yes it will work, but do you have another alternative because I can't change the code inside `doSomething()` method like I said in the post.

Comment: @warheat1990 without this change we are unable to control the behavior of that ajax call because  it's async.

Comment: You can't change the code inside `doSomehitng()` even a bit? even adding return ?

Comment: I think we need more information as to why you can't change `doSomething` or what you are trying to do. Otherwise the only solutions I can think of are very very hack-y.

Comment: @warheat1990 or you can write ajax stop setup function inside that page for the method see this link https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: JavaScript cannot wait. Anything that needs to wait for an asynchronous function to finish needs to be initiated from that function's callback (or chained to its promise, or equivalent). The linked article, and the several articles linked from there, give a canonical, comprehensive explanation to the problem as well as solution. In case you really can't change the function, then polling (via `setTimeout`, for example) for any signs of completion is the only way, really.